# Django ReadOnlyModelViewSet: get_querySet getting filtered by pk

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an endpoint that, using the url kwargs, I want to filter and return a querySet, like so: /api/myendpoint/{id}/ should return all myendpoint objects with a field X that matches {id}. I provide the get_query_set method in my view class, which is a ReadOnlyModelViewSet, that returns a queryset with all the objects that fit the criteria (this part I know works, because I print out the result before returning it and it looks correct).

The problem I seem to be having, is that the queryset getting returned by get_queryset, seems to be again filtered by django before being displayed on the endpoint. It is getting filtered such that pk=={id}. This is not the functionality that I want, because I am using {id} to filter on a different field. It seems that it is being treated as a DetailView, but I want it to be treated like a collection view (if such a thing exists). How do I return multiple objects for this view, while still using the url kwargs? I am a django beginner, so sorry if this is obvious.

urls.py:

```
  from rest_framework_nested_import routers
  router = routers.DefaultRouter()
  router.register(r'', MyView, base_name='myendpoint')

   urlpatterns = patterns('',
                  url(r'^', include(router.urls)))
```

views.py:

```
 class MyView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

 def get_queryset(self):
       if 'pk' in self.kwargs:
            return MyObj.objects.filter(field=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For returning the collection you should not pass in the `/{pk}/` since that will try and get a single object with that id, which you have seen.

The proper URL you should be using to get a list of objects is `/api/myendpoint/`. You can filter the list of objects by using `queryset` property or `get_queryset` function. However, we still need to let django know what field and value to filter by.

That's where [filtering by query parameter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-query-parameters) comes in. You could also filter in the URL string, but it's a tad more complicated because you'd need to modify your router URLs.

```
class MyView(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyObj.objects.all()
        filter_value = self.request.query_params.get('field_name', None)
        if filter_value is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(field_name=filter_value)
        return queryset
```

With this code you can hit `/api/myendpoint/?field_name=somevalue` and it will return a queryset of MyObj model filtering field_name by somevalue.

Comment: Thanks! So, there is no way to return a list of objects with a /api/myendpoint/{pk}/ endpoint? I have to use a query parameter? This makes it slightly less intuitive to use the api...

Comment: you can, but that would be an action on that object with id `{pk}` detail_route. What you're wanting to do is on the list_route http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

If you need to filter in the url itself instead of a query param, you most certainly can, but you will need to change the url routing from the default that is generated by `ViewSet` http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#filtering-against-the-url